# cannot insert data into child table SQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

basically I have 2 simple tables..the first one is called "user" which is the parent table. The PK is index auto incremented. The second table is called "useradvert". the "id" field acts as a index key which is not auto incremented. whenever I try to insert data, it does not go into the table (useradvert). There's no error at all on my PHP page. I've turned on error reporting. I manage to create a relation table without errors. I've tried to solve the problem for several days and search the internet for answers, but still could not find and understand the problem. Is the problem due to the index key (id) in the child table which is not auto incremented? Should both id key be auto incremented?

Thank you..really need your help tqs..

table definition below for "users"-parent table and "useradvert"-child table;

### -- Table structure for table `useradvert`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `useradvert` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hobby2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `users`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telno` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=97 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `users`

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `telno`, `username`, `password`, `date`) VALUES
(95, 'Test Name', '09999999999', 'test@test.com', '$2y$12$fqdmAQk5c8qk8Eh2TWy2n.AdNO.lFjqmi2ruSzk8tsVXcK71OcPae', '2015-12-24 05:00:13'),
(96, 'testtwo', '10121212121', 'test2@mail.com', '$2y$12$nHw0CjWCF5AS4VB3mjIBo.o7nxszxXh.t5FWGv3pFe5izWBOo0A0O', '2015-12-24 05:20:19');

--

### -- Constraints for dumped tables

--

### -- Constraints for table `useradvert`

ALTER TABLE `useradvert`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `useradvert_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

---

This is the user page (useracc-test.php) where the user suppose to insert the data into table "useradvert". The page display previous registered data (from table "user" and this page  also allows users to insert new data (into table "useradvert").

```
    <?php

//useracc-test.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



// require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect-test.php';


$userName= isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';




$query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();


 ?>




<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    top: 238px;
    width: 237px;
    height: 93px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 134px;
    top: 123px;
    width: 234px;
    height: 104px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 58px;
    top: 146px;
    width: 219px;
    height: 61px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#apDiv4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 302px;
    top: 102px;
    width: 365px;
    height: 123px;
    z-index: 3;
}
</style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Your Personal details:</p>
      <p><?php while($row = $res->fetch_array()): ?>
<p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['username']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['telno']; ?>





  <?php     

  // $userid = $_POST['id'];
  $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("isss", $id, $name2, $color2, $hobby2);
  $stmt->execute();
  if (!$stmt)
  { printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);}
  else {

  echo "New records created successfully";}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

    ?>  





<form name="form2" method="post" action="useracc-test.php">
        <p>INSERT YOUR INTEREST:</p>
        <p>     
        </p>
          ID:
      <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">


  <p>Name :
          <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="warna2"></label>
          Color :
          <input type="text" name="color2" id="color2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="hobi2"></label>
          Hobby:
          <input type="text" name="hobby2" id="hobby2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
       </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </form>       

               <?php endwhile; ?>

               </body>
               </html>
```

Comment: You really need to provide us with a lot more data and code examples so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: Table structure is correct, Please provide us your PHP code...

Comment: there u go.. i  already posted phpcode and table definition.

Comment: My questions is.....should BOTH keys in both tables be auto incremented??? second...why is the data not inserting to the child table??

Comment: Hi dawsonc623..thank u for ur reply...I really appreciate ur help.. but I quite can't comprehend or understand the answers....on my form.. useracc-test.php (user can retrieve and insert data)..the data they retrieve is from previous registration which was stored in table "user". then on the same page on useracc-test.php ( user can insert new data in a new table called useradvert).

Comment: This the flow of the logic which i'm trying to work on..

Comment: currently there are no errors on my relation table from which i understand at this point.... because I cannot insert any data into the child table..the relation which i created  previously.. no error prompted..

Comment: I have search many websites on the Internet.. but still could not find and understand the problem..

Comment: Woww..I never expected this question to be extremely difficult...Btw, I have a limited knowledge in PHP..and I require your help and assistant from anybody that can give or share their expertise ..tq

Comment: Should I use user emal as PK for both tables?? instead of using interger auto incremented as PK which is useless...

Comment: Im almost giving up.. I already submitted for a moderator intervention...yet to wait for their reply..

Comment: In your insert for `useradvert`, you have `(name2, color2, hobby2)`. That means your `useradvert` record is not getting a value for `id`, which violates the foreign key. You need `(id, name2, color2, hobby2)` and to provide the `user` `id` value as the value for `useradvert` `id`

Comment: Hi..I updated everything...above.. still the same...data cannot insert into table useradvert...i thought the foreign key was backwards....i tried to switch...back and forth.. but still the same....is there anything I missed???

Comment: I tried running this query in the DB...-->>>  INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2)VALUES('95','vava','vava','vava');...it was successful..meaning there's nothing wrong with the table relation.. there's something wrong now with the PHP.. not sure where..

Answer (score 0):

The indexed key does not need to be auto-incremented. Instead, you should insert your record into the `users` table, grab the `id` for that record, and manually insert that as the `id` on the `useradvert` table.

I have a sneaking suspicion your error is a foreign key constraint failure. If you check for errors after running each of your inserts, you will likely see it. The `id` you give your `useradvert` must exist as an `id` on the `users` table first.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.. I forgot the if(isset($_POST['submit']))..LoL.I did some minor changes just to add the isset above.. everything works fine now..